# Android baseline profile generation with Ktor crashing

Tags: android, ktor, baseline-profile

I'm trying to generate baseline profile for my app.

The app is using ktor to do the network calls.

I have several api calls on the splash screen but they are failing directly with :

```
failed with exception: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Domain specific configurations require that hostname aware checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[], String, String) is used
```

I have created my setup using baseline profile template from Android studio.

If I launch the app normally it works just fine.

I have no network security config defined.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the code snippet? What Android API are you targeting?